# virsh: failed to connect to hypervisor as user

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, libvirt

I'm currently running a RHEL 7.7 operating system.

I was trying to setup minkube environment using kvm2 driver, so what happens is that minikube starts pretty, but with some errors during the startup .

The error is the following:

```
'kvm2' driver reported an issue: /bin/virsh domcapabilities --virttype kvm failed:
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Cannot recv data: Connection reset by peer
```

So i start to investigate, and first what i did i tried to run the virsh command on the command line getting the same identical error, so second thing i tried is to run this command with sudo, and in this case it worked.

So i think it has to be a permission problem, but still i'm failing to solve this issue (i would like to launch minikube as user without having to use sudo).

What i tried so far:

1. Add my user in the group libvirt - Still failing
2. Add my user in the groupos: kvmuser qemu and kvm - Still failing
3. Updated the libvirtd.conf file with the following configuration:

```
unix_sock_group = "libvirt"
unix_sock_ro_perms = "0777"
unix_sock_rw_perms = "0770"
unix_sock_dir = "/var/run/libvirt"
```

4. Checked the policykit rule, that was already present with this content:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.libvirt.unix.manage"
            && subject.local
            && subject.active
            && subject.isInGroup("wheel")) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

So i tried to add my user in the wheel group, still same problem

5. Addedmy user also in the systemd-network (here i started just to random stuff lol :D) same problem.
6. Disabled selinux - same problem.

So i searched everywhere and can't find the solution to my problem, soomeone that maybe has managedo to solve it?

I just want to run vish command as a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

So after all the struggle (And btw probably adding the user to the right groups was part of the correct configuration), i was still missing one thing to get it works as a user.

Apparently it needs the following environment variable to be exported:

```
export LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system
```

After that export if the user is in an allowed group for libvirt, all commands start to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a rhel libvirt capable host handy, but with a fedora 31 following the instructions on [the libvirt dbus documentation page](https://libvirt.org/dbus.html#usage) I can run that as a wheel member user:

```
$ cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.libvirt.conf 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">

<busconfig>

  <policy group="wheel">
    <allow send_destination="org.libvirt"/>
  </policy>

</busconfig>

$ id
uid=1000(natxo) gid=1000(natxo) groups=1000(natxo),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$ virsh domcapabilities --virttype kvm
<domainCapabilities>
  <path>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</path>
  <domain>kvm</domain>
  <machine>pc-i440fx-4.1</machine>
  <arch>x86_64</arch>
  <vcpu max='255'/>
  <iothreads supported='yes'/>
  <os supported='yes'>
    <enum name='firmware'>
      <value>efi</value>
    </enum>
...
```

you may need to restart libvirtd.

Comment: that didn' t work for me. Btw i found  a solution.

Comment: I just tried on a rhel 7.7 system and it works, so interesting it didn't for you

Comment: Strange, the only thing is that there are some customization from my company on this version of redhat